# htaccess condition not working in specific dirctory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I have this htaccess file in my root dir to rewrite www to non-www

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes
        
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then in my directory for blogs I have these to help clean up the URL

```
RewriteRule ^/?author(?:/(?:.*/)?([^/]+))?/?$ index.php?author=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?tag(?:/(?:.*/)?([^/]+))?/?$ index.php?tag=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?post(?:/(?:.*/)?([^/]+))?/?$ index.php?post=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?page(?:/(?:.*/)?([^/]+))?/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

All other directories and stuff redirect to non-www correctly EXCEPT my blogs dir. I'm assuming something I did with the blog redirects is messing up the main one. How can I make my blogs directory also redir to non-www correctly?

Comment: Setting [`RewriteOptions`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) to `InheritBefore` or something could probably help. Another option would be to just to both things in the same .htaccess on the root level.

Comment: @CBroe Adding it to the root htaccess sort of works. I had to update `RewriteRule ^/?author(?:/(?:.*/)?([^/]+))?/?$ index.php?author=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` to `RewriteRule ^/?author(?:/(?:.*/)?([^/]+))?/?$ /blogs/index.php?author=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`. If I then add www to the url it redirects to example.com/author/person when it should be example.com/blogs/author/person